# Quick sort append to list with recursion?

Tags: python, recursion, quicksort

I am having a little difficulty getting this quick sort function to return an actual list instead of the items one by one. The sorting logic is working fine but it is not returning an array. Is there a way to add a persistent list that items get appended to each loop?

```
import random


def quick_sort_2(input_arr):

    if len(input_arr) == 1:
        print(input_arr[0])
        return input_arr[0]
    elif len(input_arr) == 0:
        return
    else:
        pivot = input_arr[0]
        i = 0
        left_arr = []
        right_arr = []
        while i < len(input_arr):
            if input_arr[i] < pivot:
                left_arr.append(input_arr[i])
                i += 1
            elif input_arr[i] > pivot:
                right_arr.append(input_arr[i])
                i += 1
            else:
                i += 1
        quick_sort_2(left_arr)
        print(pivot)
        quick_sort_2(right_arr)


quick_sort_2([3, 5, 2, 6, 1, 7, 0])
```

Quick side note is that I'm using print here but in reality I would want to use return somehow.

Comment: Your function only returns `None`, either explicitly in case the input list is empty, or implicitly in the other cases. You might want to add appropriate return statements and list concatenations. Also, you might want to replace the `while` loop with a `for` loop for better legibility and structure. And finally, to be precise, Python only has `list`s, not `array`s.

Comment: i added the return statement to the case if the list only contains 1 item... how would i utilize list concatenations here? everytime i call the function recursively won't it overwrite the list?

Comment: In the end you want to return a (sorted) `list`, so every return statement has to return a `list`, since you will call this recursively and aggregate the returned values. Your outermost function call (so the first function call) will then return the sorted list. You can easily concatenate two lists using `list.extend`, mutating the calling instance, or the binary `+` operator, returning a new list of the concatenation of its arguments. Take a look how the recursion is done in case of the Fibonacci sequence here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-for-nth-fibonacci-number/

Comment: i amended the top if statement to now `return input_arr` so when there is only one item, it should return the actual list. It is still not outputting a list and now it is not including the first and last item of the sorted list (0 and 7 in this example). Thank you for helping, do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: I could give you the solution, but where is the fun in that? :-) Think about what you want to return in case you are sorting the elements to the left and right of the pivot element. Ideally, just write the algorithm down on a sheet of paper for a list of few random numbers. The recursion will build "trees" to the left and the right of the pivot element, calling the same functions, thus, also building "trees", until you reach an empty or single-element list.

Comment: ok thank you for the advice, you are right I should figure it out on my own as a learning exercise. i will reply to your comment again when I figure it out!

Comment: You are loosing elements by the way.  You sort elements lesser than the pivot element before the pivot element and elements greater than the pivot element after the pivot element, but completely drop elements *equal* to the pivot element.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to actually return a result list in each branch of the function.  It may be the empty list if there is nothing to sort.  Otherwise it's the sorted list of all elements smaller than the pivot element, plus the pivot element, and the sorted list of all elements greater or equal (or not smaller) than the pivot element.

```
def quick_sort_2(items):
    items = iter(items)
    try:
        pivot = next(items)
    except StopIteration:
        return []
    else:
        left_items = []
        right_items = []
        for item in items:
            (left_items if item < pivot else right_items).append(item)
        return quick_sort_2(left_items) + [pivot] + quick_sort_2(right_items)
```